# Error diss.DWT devuelve siempre -1

Tags: r, cluster

Estoy probando el ejemplo de la función diss.DWT(), y siempre me devuelve -1 y este warning:
[1] -1
Warning message:
In diss.DWT(rbind(x, y, z)) : DWT Distance Temporarily not supported

El código es:

```
x <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
y <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
z <- sin(seq(0, pi, length.out=100))
#compute the distance
diss.DWT(rbind(x, y, z))
```

Comment: ¡Estás es [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

El error algo nos dice:

> DWT Distance Temporarily not supported

Si además revisamos el código de la función, particularmente en el repositorio del proyecto ([diss.R](https://github.com/cran/TSclust/blob/master/R/diss.R)):

```
diss.DWT <- function(series) {
  warning("DWT Distance Temporarily not supported")
  return(-1)
    # if ( length(dim(series)) == 2 ) {
    #     if ( dim(series)[1] < 2 ) {
    #         stop( "diss.DWT needs a minimum of 2 series to compute the distance, incorrect amount provided" )
    #     }
    # } else {
    #     stop( "diss.DWT series matrix with incorrect dimensions" ) 
    # }
    # wt <- wavelet.feature.extraction( series )
    # dist(wt)
}
```

vemos, que hay una gran parte de código comentada y la parte funcional simplemente es el warning y el retorno de -1. Podemos deducir con esto elementos, que los autores del paquete, por algún motivo deshabilitaron la función, más precisamente en el último commit ([historia](https://github.com/cran/TSclust/commits/master/R/diss.R)) del proyecto. Resumiendo, el warning y el retorno -1 de está función se explican por la decisión de los autores de comentar esta funcionalidad, como decía un colega: "está bien que ande mal". No encontré información del motivo, pero entiendo se lo podrías preguntar en caso de ser necesario. En el [paper](http://file:///home/pmoracho/Descargas/v62i01.pdf) del proyecto al final encontrarás los correos de los dos autores.